# Caracteres especiales en python con un .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

Estoy empezando a aprender programación y estoy empezando con python (de hecho es mi primera vez por aqui).
La cosa es que estoy siguiendo un video de mouredev y en el hace un print de un .txt. En mi .txt he escrito esto:

> Mi nombre es Adrián Mi apellido es Jiménez Tengo 26 años Y mi lenguaje
> preferido es python

Y en python pongo este codigo:

```
import os

txt_file = open("Intermediate./my_file.txt", "r+") # Leer y escribir
print(txt_file.read())
```

A lo que mi consola me devuelve:

> Mi nombre es AdriÃ¡n Mi apellido es JimÃ©nez Tengo 26 aÃ±os Y mi
> lenguaje preferido es python

Entonces mi pregunta es... Como puedo hacer para que la consola me de los caracteres cono tilde, la ñ,...

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Debes abrir el documento con la codificación correcta, probablemente: `open("Intermediate./my_file.txt", "r+", encoding="utf-8") `.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado!

Comment: En ese caso ayudarías a la comunidad cerrando la pregunta ya que no requiere más respuesta.